# will paginate with multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have following tables :

1. users
2. accounts ( user has_one account )
3. pictures ( user has_many pictures )

I want to display a User along with its related account and pictures. This is a typical N+1 queries problem and I solved it using [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations).

```
User.includes(:account, :pictures).all
```

I am trying to use `will_paginate` gem. How do I include this eager loading mechanism into `will_paginate` ?

I found a similar question here: [Using will_paginate with multiple models (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091713/using-will-paginate-with-multiple-models-rails). But the links in the answer are out of place and the answer itself is quite old. Furthermore, it uses raw sql queries, which I don't prefer.

I want the output as follows :

```
user.name account.field1 account.field2 picture.count
abc1       abcf1          abcf2           4
zxc        zxcf1          zxcf2           7
```

So basically when I do `user.name` , it will not execute a query but just get the data from the variables;
same way when I do `user.account.field1` it should fetch it from the variable and not execute a query.

Comment: The question you linked to, and your own question seem different. The OP on that question wanted to list 2 different models in the same list. This is not what you are trying to do, am I right?

Comment: Or do you want to paginate the `user.pictures` listing?

Comment: You are absolutely right.. questions are little different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally used pagination on a array rather than the gem itself.

```
    current_page = Integer(params[:page]||1)
    per_page = 250
    @users_r = User.all(:conditions=>"some condition",:limit=>per_page,:offset=>per_page*(current_page-1),:include=>[:account,:user_info ,:pictures])
    count = @users_r.length
    @users = WillPaginate::Collection.create(current_page, per_page, count) do |user|
      user.replace(@users_r)
    end
    @users.paginate(params)
```

Answer (score 4):

The `paginate` method is similar to `all` method. So you can simply do this:

```
User.includes(:account, :pictures).paginate(
  :page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

*OR*

```
User.paginate(:include=> [:account, :pictures], 
  :page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

**Note:**

The `will_paginate` gem provides a convenience method on the `Array` class for pagination:

```
[1,2,3,4].paginate(:page => 1, :per_page=>2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the info.. will try out the new gem